# What is the meaning of 'This state machine is not statically compilable' in F#?

Tags: f#

I have this warning that I don't understand at all:

```
/src/Services/APIServer/ChartData.fs(236,13): warning FS3511: This state machine is not statically compilable. A resumable code invocation at '(246,16--246,22)' could not be reduced. An alternative dynamic implementation will be used, which may be slower. Consider adjusting your code to ensure this state machine is statically compilable, or else suppress this warning. [/src/Services/APIServer/APIServer.fsproj]
```

What does it mean?

This is the code in question, the match line

```
// check user products permission
match! Products.validateAsync ctx interval fromTime toTime with
| false ->
    return! RequestErrors.FORBIDDEN String.Empty next ctx

| true ->
    // does the range include today?
```

But in general, what is the meaning of this warning?

Comment: There isn't much to go on here, but a match bang followed by a return bang? Sure the last bang should be there?

Answer (score 1):

According to [this Github issue](https://github.com/dotnet/fsharp/issues/12038), the F# compiler has two ways of implementing `task` expressions: static (fast) and dynamic (slower).

In your case, it looks like the compiler couldn't create a static implementation, so it fell back to a dynamic one instead. This seems to happen unexpectedly in some cases due to an [open issue](https://github.com/dotnet/fsharp/issues/12839) in the compiler.